# What exactly is happening when we do if(aValue) where aValue is a pointer?

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion

Is an implicit conversion/coercion of the pointer happening? If so to what type?

Is this **exactly** equivalent to if(aValue != nil) in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

*Is this exactly equivalent to if(aValue != nil) in both cases?*

Yes.  You're just testing that the pointer is a non-zero value.   Could be garbage.  Could point to any random object.  Doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

`if(aValue)` checks if the value is non-zero, as in C-based languages 0 corresponds to `false`, and non-zero corresponds to `true`.

`if(aValue != nil)` checks if value is different of `nil`, and `nil` is defined as `(id)0`.

Thus both scenarios compare `aValue` to zero.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning comes from the C language, of which Objective-C is a superset. In C the `if` statement doesn't actually test for boolean true/false, but whether the expression is non-zero.

Therefore when the expression in an `if` is of any pointer type the "then" branch is selected if the pointer value is non-zero and the `else` branch when it is 0 (aka `nil`). So:

> Is this exactly equivalent to if(aValue != nil) in both cases?

Yes.